# Show deprecation error when tags account has only one image with instagram api

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I use this URL to get images from Instagram:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tag_name/media/recent?access_token=AccessToken
```

I can retrieve successfully when tags account has many photos.
But when I use my testing account which has only one profile image. I got this error.

```
{
    "data":[],
    "pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},
    "meta":{"code":200}
}
```

I tried by adding parameters `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` in the URL but it doesn't work. And I tried all urls of tags from instagram developer website.

Can anyone help me?
I'm really glad if you help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not an `error`. It is `deprecation warning`.  `meta`:`code` = `200` means `OK`. You just got empty `data`. Check, if your photo with testing `hashtag` has less then 15 hashtags (including hashtags in comments). Try create photo with only 1 hashtag. Try to wait. For more information, write your `hashtag` and give an photo example with it.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, now i uploaded a photo with one hashtag but my data [] is still empty.

Comment: Also read newest in API. You need `public_content` scope since 11/18/2015 to get media, even by `tag`: [Scopes](http://instagram.com/developer/authorization/), [Media by tag Endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent)